# Qu'est-ce que v.s. Qu'est-ce qui

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I've heard that "qu'est-ce qui" means "what" as a subject, and that "qu'est-ce que" means "what" was an object in interrogative expressions. Is this true? Thank you.

Comment: @Circeus I don't think so.

Comment: We have literally a dozen plus questions about *que* and *qui*. That "qu'est-ce" us involved **changes nothing about the answer**.

Comment: @Circeus I'm sorry, I asked a similar question to this one just a while ago, and thought that that was the one that you were referring to. This question may be a duplicate. Thanks.